# How to remove unwanted character in file path using Android

Tags: android

How can I remove comma, opening and closing square bracket after the new image path appears in the Toast??

**Consider the following code:**

```
btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveAlbum);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                  if (requestCode == 200 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        String[] apath = data.getStringArrayExtra("all_path");
                        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (String string : apath) {
                            strings.add(string);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, strings.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

**Sample Image**

[image]

Comment: Check out string functions like substring and indexOf.

Comment: I cant apply substring to my code??

Comment: Well, share some code where you're using this path.

Comment: I posted the code.

Comment: Please do not remove complete posts after you have been helped. Is this your way to say thank?

Comment: @greenapps My sincerest apology, I already undelete the post... :(

Comment: Instead of using an `ArrayList` and afterwards removing unwanted characters you could much better use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @greenapps The solution I made may seem off-topic but I have used an Iterator to loop through each image path. The comma, opening and closing bracket are now gone. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
String myString = "[mytext]";
myString = myString.replace("[", "");
myString = myString.replace("]", "");

String[] parts = myString.split(",");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];
...
```

Comment: myString.replace is not working for me. Opening and square bracket is still there

Comment: @JakeAarons I'm afraid you're one of those guys, for whom the typical solutions fail to work. My sincerest regrets, man :'(